# How do I add CSS (transition) to an item from a SVG file?

Tags: css, svg, transition

I've created an illustration in Adobe Illustration, which I want to use on a webpage. I also would like to add some CSS transitions to a few items in the illustration. Those items consist each of multiple Illustrator layers.

To add CSS to such thing, I would think of a SVG format file. The problem is: How do I add CSS (transition) to a certain item from a SVG file, instead of the whole file itself?

When I check the uncompressed SVG code, I do see thinks such as `<g id="Guitar">` and other items with ID's.

Based upon that, I would think of `#guitar:hover { transform:rotate(4deg);transition: all 0.4s ease;}`

But I'm unsure about that.

I hope for some feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Before giving any answers, what did you try?

Comment: Honestly, nothing yet. I was wondering for about 10 minutes, but did not came up with any answer. However, while I was writing, I did came up with the assumption/answer, which I wrote in my question post. Further than that, I don't know anything. This is the first time I'm using SVG's so..

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer Wondering wouldn't get you far. If you don't know trial-and-error is a good approach…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. There are three things you need to take into account though:

1. If you want to target SVG elements with your css, the stylesheet must be inside that SVG, like [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OPpp6TSmeZlAqzjpXB1P?p=preview)
2. If the svg is loaded using an IMG tag, you can always target the `IMG` itself. If that SVG contains css files though, they will not apply since an image has to be loaded in a single request, so loading a SVG file that it iself loads a CSS file using an `IMG` tag, the styling will not work
3. If you load the SVG as a background image, the browser handles it as an image file, not as an SVG document. So things like `:hover`, `:focus` and `:active` will not work

Comment: Uhm, perhaps I'm creating a new level of difficulty here.. Or I should just re-read your answer. The SVG item is loaded as a background-image. The center of the image should be the center of your screen. So even when the viewport is smaller than the image itself, the image stays in place. With a simple image within the html with absolute position, that's not possible. That's why I've used it as a background-image. Thanks!

Comment: You never mentioned that you want to use this SVG as a background image... I have a feeling that this will not work (since you can't "hover" a background image... This is a CSS property, not a DOM element), but will need to look this up

Comment: Hm, that makes much sense. I will try to load the SVG as a DOM element, instead of a CSS background image. Perhaps with some good positioning and X Y margining, I can center the image, no matter the viewport size. After that, I can use the way you said I should style it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can style the SVG elements using the same CSS selectors you would normally use for HTML

Comment: So what I had written `(#guitar { attributes } )` was correct? :)